# Msbuild extremely slow compilation time

Tags: msbuild

Org is using TFS and msbuild for a large .Net code base with multiple daily deployments. Our builds fly on dedicated build servers except when the build compiles. This is partly due to the repo architecture, but is there a way to speed up compilation and/or msbuild alternatives that might do a better job?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? How's your build definition like? Could you elaborate "Our builds fly on dedicated build servers except when the build compiles"? Do you mean your project build slowly in TFS? If this is the case, please try to build the project locally to see how long it takes to build the project.

Comment: We are running TFS 2015, but I'm talking about the build on a dedicated build server. All steps in the build complete quickly except compilation.

Comment: If you build the project with MSBuild command line manually on the dedicated build server, how's the speed? Is your query related to TFS?

Comment: We've tried many options and tests, including that. No difference. Not sure what your second question means

Comment: How about run the project on another machine? Is the speed the same as on the dedicated build server?

Comment: We have tried numerous settings, tests, etc. Everything runs pretty fast except for the compilation time, which is around 29 minutes on a Nutanix VM, about an hour on a VMWare VM, and about 15 mins on an physical desktop with a 3+Ghz CPU. This suggests the compilation is synchronus for some reason. We are looking for insight into why this is happening, and what alternatives (third party, etc) that may be better at this than MSBuild that others may have used. Thanks.

Comment: At least, run MSBuild with diagnostic logging (`/v:diag`) and then analyze where the slowness comes from. Note that it generates tons of lines, so the analysis itself would require your patience and some skills. If you are not confident, you might also open a support case with Microsoft.